# word-wrap for contenteditable div placeholder

Tags: html, css

I have a placeholder string in a contenteditable div. The string is not displaying in a decent way. The words are broken at the end of a line.
Kindly please help. I need the words to be broken only when it's longer than the line, otherwise, the word should start from next line. I've add word-warp as break-word in the box, but seems not working.

html:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="box"></div>
```

css:

```
#box:empty:not(:focus):before{
  content:"hello thank you thank you very much hello thank you thank you very much how are you";
  font-style:italic;
  color:red;
}
#box{
  white-space: pre;
  border:1px solid lightgrey;
  height: 250px; 
  width: 350px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Payson/wwgud8vh/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `white-space` property is used to describe how whitespace inside the element is handled. You can read the [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) documentation.

Changing your code to :

```
#box{
    white-space: normal;
    /* white-space: pre-line; */
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    height: 250px; 
    width: 350px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[UpdatedFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitjsguy/wwgud8vh/1/)
   Also [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/) has bunch of good examples to explain `white-space`.